# how can I run a application created using mysql without mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I have created a application using python and mysql. how can I run it on a machine which have not installed mysql and python

Comment: Install Python and MySQL, after that it might work.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to embed those two so that the application is more easily distributable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Python from here.  https://www.python.org/downloads/

Install MySQL from here. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Use `MySQLdb` to connect `mysql` database in `Python`. Here is the link.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

After installation, you can run your application on this machine. And if you have new error then, tell me.

Comment: The OP asked specifically `how can I run a application created using mysql+python on a machine without mysql+python`? Your solution is indeed installing mysql+python! If there is no solution to the OP's actual question then the correct answer is simply `No solution`. It would be great if you can confirm that there is no hack and one must install mysql+python and add this info to ur answer. It will be good for the future reference. :)